# Replacement for Ikea backboard

Tags: particle-board

I am trying to move an [Ikea Pax closet](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/50214560/). And even though I tried to gently remove the backboard (put a stick against the edge from inside along the board and hit the stick so it would distribute the power), it still left all the nails in. I removed the nails but now I am not sure I can reuse the backboard.

It doesn't look like Ikea sells replacement backboards (so much for their promise of helping re-use). I am sure Home Depot- or Lowes-type stores sell some kind of hardboard, but is there anything specific I should think of / ask for when getting it?

Or if anyone knows an Ikea parts replacement place that has the backboards, that would be even better.

Comment: Ikea wants to sell new furniture. A lot of parts that should be available separately for their furniture aren't, starting with [removable, washable but not purchasable separately] chair covers for quite a few of their chairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great time to upgrade to a better material.  Ikea's backboards are the cheapest thing they can possibly use.

You could use a variety of hardboards, luaun plywood (which you stain to suit first) or even a clear or translucent polycarbonate and backlight it.

Comment: I actually ended up doing basically the other suggestion, but in all honesty this is the better solution if you have the time to do it, ikea backboard is not good.

Answer (score 2):

The backboard is part of the anti-racking structure and very much needed and used by just about every closet.

Backboard where the nails where pulled through can be reused a few times by putting the nails into new holes. At least until the edge is too chewed up.

As for replacement you can take a chunk of the board with you.

Comment: What’s “anti-racking structure” mean? What can happen if some of the backboard has detached?

Comment: @Jon the closet can collapse sideways. the backboard protects against that

Comment: "Racking" in this context means twisting out of square.   The whole assembly could lean sideways which is not good.  To the extreme it could tear out the connectors and collapse.  When you nail that back board on, you should check for square, and that locks in the alignment and resists that movement.

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I found this great tip for taking the nails out of the back of a Pax. Worked like a charm. And, for me, I used this tip before I took the board off so the board survived.

Use a flathead screwdriver to pry the nails up. You can use a hammer to gently nudge the tip of the screwdriver under the nail head. Then the board stays mostly in good shape and can be easily reused.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sedYDd30a5U

Comment: If you happen to have a Tack Puller, it's even easier.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the back boards I use a long piece of wood from the inside over each nail point and give a a short sharp tap from a hammer.

That has enough force to fully take the nail strait out without damaging the board or anything.

To reuse the same hole I shove a tooth pic into each hole and snap it (snip it) flush.

P.s. I've moved about 100 of these wardrobes for people

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/151092)